# How to lowercase of individual word in two dimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two-dimensional list:

```
list=[["Hello", "mY", "WORLD"], ["MY", "yOur", "ouRS"]]
```

My desired output is:

```
new_list=[["hello", "my", "world"], ["my", "your", "ours"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a list comprehension which contains, as its elements, another list comprehension. At the root of it all is a call to `str.lower()` to create new lower-casified strings.

*Aside: it is better not to name your variables after built-in types. Try `my_list=`, `lst=`, or some descriptive name like `mixed_case_words=`, instead of `list=`*

```
new_list = [ [ item.lower() for item in sublist ] for sublist in old_list]
```

If you prefer loops, you can do it with nested `for` loops:

```
new_list = []
for sublist in old_list:
    new_sublist = []
    for item in sublist:
        new_sublist.append(item.lower())
    new_list.append(new_sublist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
list=[["Hello", "mY", "WORLD"], ["MY", "yOur", "ouRS"]]
new_list = [ [ i.lower() for i in innerlist ] for innerlist in list]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[['hello', 'my', 'world'], ['my', 'your', 'ours']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested list comprehension will do for your case

```
lst = [["Hello", "mY", "WORLD"], ["MY", "yOur", "ouRS"]]
new_lst = [ [i.lower() for i in j] for j in lst]
# [["hello", "my", "world"], ["my", "your", "ours"]
```

We can do something like below also using `eval` and `str` method, this shall handle any depth of nested list of string

```
lst = [["Hello", "mY", "WORLD"], ["MY", "yOur", "ouRS"]]
# replace eval with ast.literal_eval for safer eval
new_lst = eval(str(lst).lower())
# [["hello", "my", "world"], ["my", "your", "ours"]
```